# The user login first time then send it to the reset page or send to edit page

Tags: php, html

I am developing the login module and I have two scenarios:

1. Once the user login the first time with a dummy password then the user will redirect to the reset password page and reset the password accordingly.
2. After resetting the password the user will log in with a new password and will redirect to the edit page.

For the first scenario, I have created one column called `is_first_login` and the value is `0`. After resetting the password it will change from `0` to `1`

Now my issue is, when I insert the dummy password then it's stuck on the process.php page.

Is there anything missing in my code?

```
function login($pdo) {
    if (!filter_var($_POST['username'] ?? '', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = '<label class="text-danger fs-6 pt-2">Please enter the valid email id</label>';
        header('Location: index.php?id=1');
        exit();
    } elseif (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = '<label class="text-danger fs-6 pt-2">Please enter the valid password</label>';
        header('Location: index.php?id=1');
        exit();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT company_id,company_email,password,is_first_login FROM company21 WHERE company_email=:username AND password=:password and is_active=1";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam('username', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->bindParam('password', $_POST['password']);
    $stmt->execute();

    if (!$stmt->rowCount()) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = '<label class="text-danger fs-6 pt-2">Email & Password does not match1</label>';
        header('Location: index.php?id=1');
        exit();
    }
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //print_r($result);

    if (!empty($result['is_first_login']) && $result['is_first_login'] == 0) {
        header("Location:reset-password.php");
        exit();
    }

    if (!empty($result['is_first_login']) && $result['is_first_login'] == 1) {
        // echo "working1";
        if (!password_verify($_POST['password'], $result['password'])) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = '<label class="text-danger fs-6 pt-2">Email & Password does not match2</label>';
            header('Location: index.php?id=1');
            exit();
        } else {
            $_SESSION['company_id'] = $result['company_id'];
            $_SESSION['company_email'] = $result['company_email'];

            header("Location:edit-company.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the output in the result if the first-time user login.

```
Array ( [company_id] => 2 [company_email] => abc@gmail.com [password] => 5JXB6W [is_first_login] => 0 )
```

Comment: It‘s kind of hard to say if you are missing something because your explanation is a bit weird. Nevertheless I think you will have to start the Session by calling `session_start()` at the very first line of your code: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: @mpm, I already added the session_start() at the top of the file. I just shared the login module. Let me know what code you haven't understood. I'll explain you again.

Comment: It’s more like the basic idea: Why would you give users a random password and than have the user reset the password? That’s just very annoying for the user?

Comment: @mpm, The username, and password will be created by the Master admin and then the Master admin will share the details over the email with the respective users. Not every user can access the portal.

Comment: Ah ok thx, now I understood!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know it is the right way or not but this code has solved my issue. I am open to better solutions.

What I did: I have created one more column called `"temp_password"` in the database and added my all the dummy password in that.

Note: Now I have 2 columns for password one for hash password and second for dummy password.

Now when the user login then I am first checking the password is the hash password. If hash then redirecting to the edit page if match.

If the password is not hash then I am comparing the password with the `temp_password`. If match then redirecting to the reset page and if not match then displaying the error message `"Email & Password does not match"`.

```
function login($pdo) {

    if (!filter_var($_POST['username'] ?? '', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = '<label class="text-danger fs-6 pt-2">Please enter the valid email id</label>';
        header('Location: index.php?id=1');
        exit();
    } elseif (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = '<label class="text-danger fs-6 pt-2">Please enter the valid password</label>';
         header('Location: index.php?id=1');
          exit();
    }

  $sql = "SELECT company_id,company_email,password,is_first_login,temp_password FROM company21 WHERE company_email=:username and is_active=1";
     $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bindParam('username', $_POST['username']);
     $stmt->execute();
     $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          if (!password_verify($_POST['password'], $result['password'])) {
            if ($_POST['password']==$result['temp_password']) {
                  header('Location: reset-password.php');
                  exit();
            }
            else{
            $_SESSION['error'] = '<label class="text-danger fs-6 pt-2">Email & Password does not match</label>';
            header('Location: index.php?id=1');
            exit();
          }

            }
           else{
            $_SESSION['company_id'] = $result['company_id'];
            $_SESSION['company_email'] = $result['company_email'];

            header("Location:edit.php");
            exit();

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have used the empty() function it will return true if the following values evaluate to empty:

```
0
0.0
"0"
""
NULL
FALSE
array()
```

so, change that to make the condition work.

Change Code:-

```
function login($pdo) {

    if (!filter_var($_POST['username'] ?? '', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = '<label class="text-danger fs-6 pt-2">Please enter the valid email id</label>';
        header('Location: index.php?id=1');
        exit();
    } elseif (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = '<label class="text-danger fs-6 pt-2">Please enter the valid password</label>';
         header('Location: index.php?id=1');
          exit();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT company_id,company_email,password,is_first_login FROM company21 WHERE company_email=:username AND password=:password and is_active=1";
     $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bindParam('username', $_POST['username']);
     $stmt->bindParam('password', $_POST['password']);
     $stmt->execute();

    if (!$stmt->rowCount()) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = '<label class="text-danger fs-6 pt-2">Email & Password does not match1</label>';
        header('Location: index.php?id=1');
        exit();
    }
     $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     //print_r($result);

     if ($result['is_first_login']==0) {
        header("Location:reset-password.php");
        exit();
        }

     if($result['is_first_login']==1) {
         // echo "working1";
            if (!password_verify($_POST['password'], $result['password'])) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = '<label class="text-danger fs-6 pt-2">Email & Password does not match2</label>';
            header('Location: index.php?id=1');
            exit();
            }
           else{
            $_SESSION['company_id'] = $result['company_id'];
            $_SESSION['company_email'] = $result['company_email'];

            header("Location:edit-company.php");
            exit();

            }

         }
}
```

Comment: Apologize for the late reply,  When $result['is_first_login']==1 then I am getting the issue. I think something issue with my sqlquery because password always get wrong